# Ajax concatenate fields

Tags: ajax, json, concatenation

I'm currently building a form, and trying to limit the amount of fields I have to use.

I have three fields currently first name, middle initial, and last name.  When these are combined they would be called "Display Name".

Is there a way to combine fields or would it have to be entered separately?

```
        "Fname": $('#fname').val(),
        "MInit": $('#minit').val(),
        "Lname": $('#lname').val(),
```

Comment: `"name" : fname + mini + lname`, basically?

Comment: Yeah, would it be as simple as that?  Then assigning it to a new field that isn't displayed?